# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this query that is based on a `@Amount` parameter

```
Amount varchar(20)= NULL

SELECT .....
    Format(T1.Amount, 'c', 'en-us') as Amount1, 
    Format(T2.Amount, 'c', 'en-us') as Amount2
FROM Table1
WHERE  .....
    AND (T1.Amount>= CAST(@Amount AS INT) OR T2.Amount >= CAST(@Amount AS INT)) 
    AND @Amount IS NOT NULL
```

If the `@Amount` parameter is not `NULL` **and is numeric** the query works perfectly, but if the `@Amount` parameter is `'%'` or `NULL` I get the above conversion error.

Any idea on how to solve that?

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using? SQL Server 2012+ supports the [TRY_PARSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx) function which could help you.

Comment: why do you think you can convert a `%` value to an int?

Comment: you can also use IsNumeric function and set value by apply case with IsNumeric function .

Comment: @diiN__________, yes, I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @Tanner I understand that I can't so I'm asking what can I do about it..

Comment: @user3378165 seeing as the query won't work with that value at all, wrap the code in a block that checks if it's a valid value first and only execute if a valid value is present.

Comment: @Tanner This is what I am looking for, but i Im not sure how to do it because I have many other condtions on this query, could you give me an example?

Comment: @user3378165 what sql version are you using?

Comment: @Tanner I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: What do you want the query to do if you pass `%` value in the parameter? And what should it do if you pass `NULL`?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov If I pass `%` I want the query to ignore this condition, if I pass a numeric value I want only results that one of their amounts are less than the passed value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple approach to check if the value is numeric:

```
DECLARE @Amount VARCHAR(20)= '23';

IF ISNUMERIC(@Amount) = 0
    BEGIN   
        PRINT 'Amount is null or is not a number';
    END;
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Amount: ' + @Amount;
    END;
```

To do it in the `WHERE` clause:

```
DECLARE @Amount VARCHAR(20)= '23';

SELECT 'Some Data' AS Result
WHERE ISNUMERIC(@Amount) = 1 AND @Amount > 0
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to check it within the `WHERE` clause?!

Comment: With some little changes, I got it to work, the `IF ELSE` was a great idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the proper `int` type for the `@Amount` parameter?
Why do you use `varchar`?

I would make the type of the `@Amount` parameter `int` and pass actual value or `NULL`. Passing `NULL` would indicate that this parameter should be ignored.

```
@Amount int = NULL

SELECT .....
    Format(T1.Amount, 'c', 'en-us') as Amount1, 
    Format(T2.Amount, 'c', 'en-us') as Amount2
FROM 
    T1 ... JOIN T2 ...
WHERE  
    .....
    AND (@Amount IS NULL OR T1.Amount >= @Amount OR T2.Amount >= @Amount) 
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

---

This type of the query is called [Dynamic Search Condition](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html). I recommend to read this article by Erland Sommarskog for detailed explanations and why `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is important for this type of queries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's a requirement to have the `@Amount` parameter as a `varchar`.